# What does "source" do in Mac iTerm2 terminal?

Tags: macos, iterm2

I put in the command `source` followed by my file path and I was wondering what the `source` command does in the iTerm2 terminal?

Any help on this would be welcome.

Comment: Like in any shell, `source` executes the command passed as an argument in the context of the current shell. Try `man source` for more information.

Answer (score 2):

`source` is a shell builtin related to a shell such as [tcsh](https://www.tcsh.org/), [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), or [zsh](https://www.zsh.org/) and not to a terminal application such as [iTerm2](https://iterm2.com/).

According to `man source`:

> Shell builtin commands are commands that can be executed within the running shell's process.

You can find more details, in the [zsh manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/index.html):

> source file [ arg ... ]
>
> Same as ‘.’, except that the current directory is always searched and is always searched first, before directories in $path.

and

> . file [ arg ... ]
>
> Read commands from file and execute them in the current shell environment.

In few words, `source file` executes the commands in `file`.